# Toggle menu to add cookie/remove cookie on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a toggle menu which I want to add a cookie too, so that if the page is refreshed or the user goes to another page on the site, the menu will remain open, here is my current code:

```
$('nav #mobileMenu').on('click', function(){
        var isToggled = $(this).data('isToggled');
        if(isToggled){
            $("nav#menu").addClass("mobileMenuActive");
            $("nav ul").fadeIn(1000);
            $("nav em").fadeOut('fast');      
        } else {
            $("nav#menu").removeClass("mobileMenuActive");
            $("nav ul").fadeOut(1000);
            $("nav em").fadeIn('fast');   
        }

        $(this).data('isToggled', !isToggled)
    });
```

I have tried many attempts but they don't do what I want which is the cookie should be added when the user has first clicked on 'nav #mobileMenu's and then removed, also the class to be removed 'mobileMenuActive' if the user clicks again on 'nav #mobileMenu' if they only click once on 'nav #mobileMenu' the cookie will remain for 1 day allowing them if they go to another page of the site or refresh the page the menu will stills have the class 'mobileMenuActive'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a plugin called [`jQuery.cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to make all your cookie stuff easier.

```
$('nav #mobileMenu').on('click', function() {
    // Get it from the cookie or data.
    if ($.cookie('isToggled') != undefined)
      var isToggled = $.cookie('isToggled');
    else
      var isToggled = $(this).data('isToggled');
    if(isToggled) {
        $("nav#menu").addClass("mobileMenuActive");
        $("nav ul").fadeIn(1000);
        $("nav em").fadeOut('fast');
    } else {
        $("nav#menu").removeClass("mobileMenuActive");
        $("nav ul").fadeOut(1000);
        $("nav em").fadeIn('fast');   
    }

    $(this).data('isToggled', !isToggled)
    $.cookie('isToggled', !isToggled, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
})
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen for that

Comment: @GrahamBarnes Optional buddy. Better you put.

Comment: Unfortunately, when the user goes to another page on the site, the menu isn't staying open, I can see in firebug the cookie 'isToggled' toggles between true and false on click but if its true the menu needs to stay open, if false it should fade out, how can I adjust my code appropriately?

Comment: @GrahamBarnes You have to use the cookies buddy. See now.